# improper integral calculation

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I do not know how to solve this integral and then expand the result in powers of $t$

$$(1-t)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(\frac{2x^2t}{1+t}\right)}{1+x^2}dx=?,~~~~|t|<1.$$

any idea?

Comment: The integral doesn't seem to converge. e^{x^2}?

Comment: It makes sense only for $-1<t<0$. Are you assuming this?

Comment: Use [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[E^%28-x^2%29%2F%28x^2+%2B+a^2%29%2C{x%2C-Infinity%2CInfinity}%2CAssumptions-%3E{a%3E0}]) after appropriate change of variables. Of course, that would require some assumptions on $t$ (see previous comments).

Comment: @Norbert, doesn't it converge also for $t<-1$?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that $t$ is such that the integral converges.  Now let's consider

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{1+x^2}$$

where $a \gt 0$.  We may evaluate this integral using Parseval's theorem, which states that, for functions $f$ and $g$, each having Fourier transforms $F$ and $G$, respectively, then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \, g^*(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, F(k) \, G^*(k)$$

Now, if $f(x) = e^{-a x^2}$ and $g(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, then

$$F(k) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{-k^2/(4 a)}$$

$$G(k) = \pi \, e^{-|k|}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{1+x^2} &= \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, e^{-k^2/(4 a)} e^{-|k|}\\ &= \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} 2 \int_0^{\infty} dk \, e^{-k^2/(4 a)} e^{-k} \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^a \int_0^{\infty} dk \, e^{-(k+2 a)^2/(4 a)} \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \sqrt{\pi a} e^a \text{erfc}{\sqrt{a}}\\ &= \pi e^a \text{erfc}{\sqrt{a}} \end{align}$$

Now, $a=-2 t/(1+t)$ for $t \in (-1,0)$.  To plug in, use the fact that $\text{erfc}{(y)} = 1-\text{erf}{(y)}$, where

$$\text{erf}{\sqrt{a}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{a^k}{k! (2 k+1)}$$

Comment: thaks, but would happen if $a <0$?

Comment: @Cristian: no, the integral simply will not converge for those values of $a$.

Comment: sorry Ron Gordon, you have the literature of the show you did?

Comment: @Cristian: I apologize, I do not understand your question.

Comment: you have references or bibliography of the proof?

Comment: @Cristian: this is my work.  I do not have a reference to this specific derivation.  To learn the technique, however, I would consult any textbook covering Fourier analysis.