# calculating this improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have problems when calculating this improper integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+x^2}e^{\frac{2x^2t}{1+t}}dx~= ~?~~~|t|<1$$

assistance would be helpful.

Comment: you can reduce it to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{1+x^2}dx$ with $a=\frac{t-1}{t+1}$. For evaluation of that integral see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/447708/19538)

Comment: @Norbert - the integrals are not quite the same.

Comment: @nbubis what is wrong with my reduction?

Comment: @Norbert - just fine, but I don't think it should be closed as a dupe.